# Why is Maple not evaluating my definite integral

Tags: maple

I am trying to evaluate a definite integral over the interval [a,b] but Maple is producing the same integral which I am trying to solve. A picture is shown below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrJ17.jpg)

Please help (I am a new Maple user)

When I try to solve it as an indefinite integral, I get a correct result. However, I want the solution as a definite integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on whether or not `b>a`.

```
int(-v*R*T/(v-b)^2+2*a/b^2,v=a..b)
  assuming b>a;

    -signum(R*T*b)*infinity

int(-v*R*T/(v-b)^2+2*a/b^2,v=a..b)
  assuming b<a;

    signum(R*T*b)*infinity

int(-v*R*T/(v-b)^2+2*a/b^2,v=a..b,
    allsolutions);

    piecewise(a < b,-signum(R*T*b)*infinity,
              b = a,0,
              b < a,signum(R*T*b)*infinity)
```